# In ssh config file , can I use "Host" as parameter? If not, how can I make ssh config file accept parameter?

Tags: ssh

in .ssh/config file

Scenario is that
I have two public ips now (dynamic), one is connect to aws and one is connect to rackspace

Both require different pem keys to connect. But I want to use ssh config file to save my time

```
Host <ip1> 
User root
Port 22
HostName %h
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.pem

Host <ip2> 
User root
Port 22
HostName %h
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rackspace.pem
```

From this setting, i cannot distinguish which pem file to be use.
I want to make use of the Host as part of parameter to specify which server to connect to
e.g. ssh aws-ip1
ssh rack-ip2

then the config file can distinguish which pem file to use

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok... This question is very old. Yet I can think of a way that will help in these kind of scenarios. Using wildcard(*) and %h parameters here.

Let's assume Amazon's IP as 10.10.20.* and Rackspace IP as 20.20.10.*. The following config will help:

```
Host 10.10.20.*
    Hostname %h
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.pem

Host 20.20.10.*
    Hostname %h
    User root
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rackspace.pem
```

And then calling, say `ssh 10.10.20.5` will call something like `ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem root@10.10.20.5`, which is what might just be required.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Host' part is kind of 'shortcut' you can use:

```
Host aws-ip1
    HostName ip-or-name-to-ip1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/aws.pem

Host rack-ip2
    HostName ip-or-name-to-ip2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rackspace.pem
```

and then you just use `ssh aws-ip1` or `ssh rack-ip2` ...

To quote from `man ssh-config`:

```
Host    Restricts the following declarations (up to the next Host key-
        word) to be only for those hosts that match one of the patterns
        given after the keyword.
```

Comment: Thx: but how can I pass ip1, ip2 to hostname?

Comment: you write the ip-address behind the "Hostname" statement. maybe you did not asked exactly what you wanted. do you need a group of hosts having the same setting?

Comment: then this would be hardcodeded, my question is that how can I pass the parameter using Host, both IP address are dynamically, I want sth that we can pass parameter into HostName

Comment: well, you might go with `HostName %h` in .ssh/config and then you might use `ssh aws-ip1 -o HostName real_ip`

Comment: Do you mind describe more how to use %h? If %h is accepted from "Host", then I cannot distinguish aws or rackspace...

Comment: use the alias-solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use plain old-school shell aliases:

```
 alias ssh_rack="ssh -i .ssh/rackspace.pem"
 alias ssh_aws="ssh -i .ssh/aws.pem"
```

and then use them instead of `ssh`.